# Accessing a web service from the client code (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-2.0

How and which tasks need to be done for accessing a web service from the client code (Java Script)?
Please help.

Comment: See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is ASP.net then following are the steps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx)

1. Writing a script method to display and invoke the methods of the service
2. Assign result to HTML elements

Here is the code,

> `<script src="WebService.asmx/jsdebug" type="text/javascript"></script>`

```
function OnMethodSucceeded(result, eventArgs)
{
    var label = Sys.UI.DomElement.getElementById('Label1');
    var sb = new Sys.StringBuilder(); 
    sb.append('You got back a value of '); 
    sb.append(result.toString()); 
    label.innerHTML = sb.toString();  
}

function OnMethodFailed(error)
{
    alert(error.get_message()); 
}
```